# How to see if an interface is connected in Centos/Linux

Tags: centos, interface

With Centos installed on a server with 2 onboard ethernet ports, how can I check which port has an IP? In windows you can go to network & sharing center and you can see the network interface with a red X to show that the cable is unplugged. In Centos what command can I run to check which interface is connected or unplugged.

Answer (score 12):

You've asked two different questions. To check if it has an *IP address*, you can use:

```
ip addr ls dev eth0  # the new iproute tools
ifconfig eth0        # old ifconfig
```

A down interface can still have an IP address. To check if the Ethernet link is up, you can:

```
ip link ls dev eth0  # look for LOWER_UP
ethtool eth0         # look for Link detected: yes
```

Note that a port may be "down" in software as well, in which case it may not have a link, despite being plugged in. You can check for that with:

```
ip link ls dev etho  # look for UP
ifconfig eth0        # look for UP / RUNNING (on the same line as the other flags)
```

The `ip` command supports a lot of advanced networking configuration that `ifconfig`/`route`/etc. do not. You should generally prefer them on Linux, but sometimes they're not installed (especially on older releases). You can still use `ifconfig`, etc., but those simply fail to display all the information—e.g., may not display a secondary IP address, or a second routing table.

Answer (score 1):

*Ifconfig* is an obsolete command. The *iproute2*  suite supersedes it, along with a large number of other utilities, including bridge-utils, route, and so on.

The correct command is

```
 ip addr show dev eth0
```

which shows whether eth0 (for instance) has an IP address assigned. You can check whether the interface is up with

```
 ip link show dev eth0
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type

```
ifconfig <interface_name> (eth0 for example)
```

If the cable is plugged you should see UP in first line of output:

```
flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way ... The easiest is by using `nmcli d`

**nmcli d**

```
[root@localhost ~]# nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s8  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
enp0s3  ethernet  connected  enp0s3             
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --                 
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Alternatively;

**service network status**

```
[root@localhost ~]# service network status
Configured devices:
lo enp0s3
Currently active devices:
lo enp0s3 enp0s8
[root@localhost ~]#
```